# Is is possible to clone a application server in Websphere

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

I have deployed an application on `server1` in Websphere 8.5.5

Can I clone it to create `server2` with the same application deployment and datasources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are in an **ND** environment you can create a server template (From the console: **Websphere Application Servers** > **Templates** > **New** ) based on the server1 and then create server2 based on this template.

This way you easily get all configuration of server1 (datasources, jvm arguments etc) into server2.

Comment: This is great.... I was able to do it.... But the application doesn't get installed for server2.

I m looking for a clone.

Comment: You should make sync with node then map the application to the new server.

Answer (score 1):

You can install WAS at same level on second machine and then use "manageprofiles -backupProfile" and "manageprofiles -restoreProfile" commands to move profile to machine2. Then use the AdminTask.changeHostName ('[-interactive]') to change hostname on the machine.

You can change nodename to different nodename using renameNode.bat also. The only thing is there will be no command to change cellname and you will have same cellname as original server.

For more details please review the link below :
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27020204